# Function of a surface area?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\iint\limits_s {y \cdot dS}$$

$$z=x+y^2$$

$0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 2$

if you graph $z$, then you get a surface in a 3d scalar field from the ranges above.
How does just $y$ in the $\iint\limits_s {y \cdot dS}$ give surface area?

Comment: The statement "$0 \ge y \ge 2$" does not make sense since $0$ is less than $2$.

Comment: i meant 0 ≤ y ≤ 2..bad keypad code

Answer (score 1):

Point 1: Did you read the problem correctly? If I am not horribly mistaken, your objective is merely to integrate the function $y$ over the (strange) surface, not to compute the surface area itself.  This is in analogy with your previous material, when you presumably found the work on an object traveling a crazy path by integrating some function over that path, not the $x$-axis (at least not directly).  [Though the analogy was imperfect, as that was presumably a vector function, and here we have a scalar integral.]

Point 2: You are correct that the given integral doesn't look like any arc-length or surface-area integral we've seen before.  Here are some ways to get the surface-area integral.

On the one hand, it's easy.  How do you get the length of an interval?  Integrate $1$ over the interval, since $\int_a^b 1 \, dx = b - a$.  Similarly for areas of rectangles in $2$-space (integrate 1 with double integral), and volumes of cubes in $3$-space (integrate 1 with triple integral).  By analogy, the surface area integral "should be" $\iint\limits_{S} 1 \, dS$. [This confirms point 1].  This isn't directly helpful, though, because the curvature and sloping of the surface means that I can't get away with $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^2 1 \, dy \, dx$.   Here are two calculation methods.

Since $z = f(x, y): = x + y^2$ defines the surface, and the natural region of integration is nice, the surface area integral should be (in analogy with the arc-length formulas in one fewer dimension)
\begin{align}
 \iint\limits_{S} 1 \,dS &= \int_0^1 \int_0^2 \sqrt{(f_x(x, y))^2 + (f_y(x, y))^2 + 1} \, dy \, dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^2 \sqrt{2 + 4y^2} \, dy \, dx,
\end{align}
though keep in mind that this is the "shortcut formula" and doesn't work well for cylinders/spheres.

To do it "right," (i.e., use a more general method) we must note that as vectors, the surface is traced out by $\mathbf{u}(x, y) = \langle x, y, x + y^2 \rangle$ for $x$, $y$ in the right range, with $\mathbf{u}_x(x, y) = \langle 1, 0, 1 \rangle$ and $\mathbf{u}_y(x, y) = \langle 0, 1, 2y \rangle$.  The magnitude of the cross product gives the area of the appropriate (approximating) parallelograms, so we have
\begin{align}
 \iint\limits_{S} 1 \, dS &= \int_0^1 \int_0^2 \vert \mathbf{u}_x \times \mathbf{u}_y \vert \, dy \, dx\\
& =  \int_0^1 \int_0^2 \vert - \mathbf{i} + 2y \mathbf{j} + \mathbf{k} \vert \, dy \, dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^2 \sqrt{(-1)^2 + (2y)^2 + 1^2} \, dy \, dx,
\end{align}
and after simplification, it's the same.

Question for you: can you use any method and rewrite $\iint\limits_S y \, dS$ as a $dx/dy$ integral with the above ideas?